# GCM Server, Java Web Service?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am creating a server for my android app that utilizes Google Cloud Messaging for the network play.  Should I be creating a Java Web service for the server, or is there something more efficient?  Is it possible to create a C# web service instead?

Answer (score 1):

Web Services are not restricted by any language, You can have it in any language, be it C# or Java or PHP

Eventually the web service would be recieveing HTTP requests from your Android device with parameters like a GCM registration id of the device, you can send other parameters also. The web service would likely insert those into a database.

So, it doesn't matter which language is the service written in. It should accept the parameters and process them accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a certain language you would recommend that would be most efficient for a GCM service?

Comment: Chose the one which you are proficient with. For the use case of GCM service, most of the languages would prove efficient. Go with JAVA if can't pick one.

Comment: Sudhir - Could you please share java code (RestFul services) to registering app to GCM? Thanks, Neha

Comment: I hope you are referring to the REST endpoint that would store the GCM ID sent to it. It depends what Framework you are using, [start here](http://crunchify.com/how-to-build-restful-service-with-java-using-jax-rs-and-jersey/)